# Связь один к одному с "двух концов"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Надо объединить две таблицы по логике: "У пользователя есть магазин, а у магазина есть владелец", т.е. в объекте Shop должна быть ссылка на User, а у User должна быть ссылка на Shop. Но выдаёт исключение `InvalidOperationException` с текстом :

The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'Owner' on type 'ConsoleApplication49.Shop' is not valid. The property 'Owner' is not a valid navigation property on the related type 'ConsoleApplication49.User'. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation property.

на MSDN нашел [InversePropertyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.inversepropertyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), вроде бы пометил, но исключение всё равно есть. Возможно ли такую связь реализовать?

```
public partial class Shop
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }//Open/Close/Blocking
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Owner")]
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
}
public partial class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Patronymic { get; set; }
    public string E_Mail { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; } //Онлайн, оффлайн, неактивирован

    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

    public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[InverseProperty("Owner")]` - совсем не обязательный атрибут.
В метод `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` контекста работы с базой надо добавить:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOptional<Shop>(a => a.Shop)
                .WithRequired(a => a.Owner);
```

В этой связке Id пользователя и магазина будут идентичными
Достать пользователя из магазина и наоборот будет не проблема

Answer (score 2):

В `InverseProperty` нужно указывать имя свойства *другого класса*, которое ссылается на этот. В вашем случае — `[InverseProperty("Shop")]`.

Comment: Ошибка не исчезает, изменился только текст ошибки
`Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'ConsoleApplication49.Shop' and 'ConsoleApplication49.User'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.`